# I want a central way to control my buttons

Tags: java, android

Hi I have 2 lines each with a name textfield, 2 buttons and a textfield to show the amount. There will be more lines later.
I want 1 button to add 1 to the amount and the other to decrease the amount by 1.
But I don't know how to get the ID from the button I press. I have gotten this far.

I hope someone can let me know. How I can get the indexvalue depending on which button  is pressed.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<Integer> ButtonUp;
    private ArrayList<Integer> Amount;
    private ArrayList<Integer> ButtonDown;
    int ArrayIndex = 0;
    int Value = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButtonUp();
        Amount();
        ButtonDown();
    }

    // ArrayList ButtonUp
    public void ButtonUp(){
        ButtonUp.add(R.id.Bup1);
        ButtonUp.add(R.id.Bup2);
    }

    // ArrayList Amount
    public void Amount(){
        Amount.add(R.id.Aantal1);
        Amount.add(R.id.Aantal2);
    }

    // ArrayList ButtonDown
    public void ButtonDown() {
        ButtonDown.add(R.id.Bdown1);
        ButtonDown.add(R.id.Bdown2);
    }

    // Get position ArrayList on press
    // Publish new Value
    public void buttonPress(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.Bup1:
                SetAmountUp(id);
                displayQuantity(Value);
                break;
            case R.id.Bup2:
                SetAmountUp(R.id.Bup2);
                displayQuantity(Value);
                break;
            case R.id.Bdown1:
                SetAmountDown(R.id.Bdown1);
                displayQuantity(Value);
                break;
            case R.id.Bdown2:
                SetAmountDown(R.id.Bdown1);
                displayQuantity(Value);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void SetAmountUp(int indexNumberUp){
        Value = Amount.get(ButtonUp.indexOf(indexNumberUp));
        Value++;
        Amount.set(ArrayIndex,Value);
    }

    public void SetAmountDown(int indexNumberDown){
        Value = Amount.get(ButtonDown.indexOf(indexNumberDown));
        Value--;
        Amount.set(ArrayIndex,Value);
    }

    // Publish number
    private void displayQuantity(int NewAmount) {
        int ID = Amount.get(ArrayIndex);
        TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(ID);
        quantityTextView.setText(NewAmount);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you add the `android:onClick` attribute to your button in the xml file you can then write a method for the button like `public void add(View v)` for the add button and `public void decrease(View v)` for the other button (then you could get the button id from the View parameter).

Comment: Why don't you just create one method to increment Value, and another to decrease it? Then put the method behind the concerning button. Done. I don't see why you need to check, which button you are using.

Comment: Oh sorry guys I think I forgot to mention, I am now working with 2 lines, so 4 buttons but it will be up to 30 or even 40 lines eventually and on each line there are 2 buttons. I'm trying to make a supply ordering app kind of thing. So I need a onclick method, that reacts on the press to give me the id and eventually the index. The index of the buttons are the same as the amount textview.

Comment: You should really use a `ListView` and a custom layout. The `ListView` will handle the amount of lines you need based off the array you give it. Then create a custom layout that holds the layout for each line. In the adapter for the `ListView` you will have a method `getView` and that is where you will assign the actions for the buttons. Some comments in your code signifying what is what would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In the layout, declare an unique id to each button, then add `android:onClick="increment"` to each button.

In your class, create the method

```
public void increment(View view) {
  switch (view.getId()){
   case R.id.yourbuttonid1:
     // do what you whant
     break;
   case R.id.yourbuttonid2:
    // do with second editext
    break
    // ....
   }


}
```

Same approach to decrease method.

Answer (score 0):

It will be much easier for you if you used a recyclerView for that